# Flutter overflow

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, overflow, stack-overflow

```
List<Transition> get RecentTransation {
  return RecentTransation.where((tx) {
    return tx.date.isAfter(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 6),),);
  }).toList();
}
```

These giving stackoverflow on emulator ,What should I change

What should I change

Comment: Please give more detail about this issue

Answer (score 0):

You are calling this method recursively so it gets in an infinitive loop. The `RecentTransation` in

```
return RecentTransation.where((tx) {
```

is the function itself. I assume it needs to be some variable that actually is the list of all transactions. I don't know what that is for you. maybe it is

```
return Transation.where((tx) {
```

Comment: How can I get recent Transactions only for this week.In different way